# PHP variable with jQuery. PHP variable undefined if using jQuery in <head></head> but works when jQuery code is used in footer

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having trouble getting a PHP variable to work with jQuery.

I define a PHP variable in the body, $x and am sending this to a PHP file.  The PHP file echo's the variable value.

Inside the jQuery script, I create a Javascript variable:

```
 var test_php_variable = <?php echo $x; ?> ;  //$x is undefined, why?
```

When this line of code is executed, it looks like $x is not defined.  I would have thought that because it is enclosed inside the $(document).ready(function() {} ); tags that it would wait for the PHP code in the HTML body to execute first.

This line of code works, but it doesn't allow me to use the variable:

```
var test_php_variable = <?php echo 10; ?> ;  // no problems with a constant
```

One interesting thing is that when I include all the jQuery code at the end of the HTML body, the code works.

Why would $x be undefined if I use this code in the HTML head?

HTML/jQuery code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--load jQuery from Google -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type ="text/javascript">
    //wait until the document is ready - maybe it is loading the javascript
    //before the document is ready?
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //the line of code below does not work, $x is not defined            
        var test_php_variable = <?php echo $x; ?> ;

        $('#Update_variable').click(function(){  
            //give a "Loading..." message
            $('div#test1 span').html('Loading...')
            //ask the server to echo "test_variable"
            //place "test_variable" in the span of #test1
                    $.get('server_response.php',
                    'test_variable=' + test_php_variable,
                    function(data){
                        $('div#test1 span').html(data);  
                    }, 'html'); //end $.get
        }); //end click  
    }); //end document ready
    </script>


</head>
<body>
   <?php $x=10; ?> <!-- it's as if the jQuery code is executing before this line of code -->
    <div id="test1">
        Some Text<br/>
        <span>replace_this_with_server_response</span>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" id ="Update_variable" value="Update">
    </div> <!-- end test1 --> 
</body>
```

server_response.php code:

```
<?php
sleep(1);
echo 'test_variable = '.$_GET['test_variable'];
?>
```

Comment: So why can't you just keep your jQuery code at the end of the body?  [It's better there anyway.](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/)

Comment: PHP code is processed before anything else. All other code is processed once the file is set to the client. You have to make sure the order of your php code is such that the values are set before you use them.

Comment: Yes, like stated by @Justin below, the php in the head is undefined because the `<body>` hasn't loaded yet... it has nothing to do with jQuery timing because the php variable has already been inserted within the `<head>` as `undefined` when your jQuery executes.

Comment: If your question was answered, you should "accept" it by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 5):

You are receiving the error because `$x` *is* undefined at that point in the script. PHP processes the page from top to bottom. To demonstrate, this code will throw an error:

```
<?php
echo $x;
$x = 10;
?>
```

...but this code will work:

```
<?php
$x = 10;
echo $x;
?>
```

This has nothing to do with jQuery. You can resolve this particular problem by putting the javascript at the bottom of the page, or at least after your `$x = 10;` line.

Comment: Thanks for the response Justin.

Comment: No, not 'anything' just 'any JavaScript'. As far as PHP is concerned it (the HTML and JS) is just text.

Comment: PHP is server-side and JavaScript is client-side. What that means is, the PHP interpreter runs *all* of the PHP code on the page __before__ it is served to the browser. Once the browser receives the page, it then executes whatever JavaScript it finds.

Answer (score 3):

All php code is executed on the server side. All javascript code is executed on the client side.

So, the server is reading:

```
var test_php_variable = <?php echo $x; ?> ;
<?php $x = 10; ?>
```

and sending

```
var test_php_variable = undefined ;
```

to the browser.

If instead you change it to:

```
<?php $x = 10; ?>
var test_php_variable = <?php echo $x; ?> ;
```

The server will send

```
var test_php_variable = 10 ;
```

to the browser.

Try looking at the server response in a tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

Answer (score 2):

PHP is processed on the server. It doesn't depend on JQuery in any way (JQuery is processed in the browser). For PHP interpreter the code looks like this:

```
blah blah
<?php echo $x; ?>
blah blah
<?php $x=10; ?>
blah blah
```

It is now obvious that you read `$x` before defining its value.